# Websitepanel and / or IIS : Create a global DNS / subdomain redirect for users to access the control panel. I.e. cp.whateverdomain.com

Tags: iis, iis-7, dns

As per my subject, I need ideas / help on creating [cp].whateverdomain.com, and loading the control panel when that gets hit.

I want this to be a "global" setting, affecting all domains. I understand binding to a port, but I don't understand how to "bind" the control panel to a [cp] subdomain for all domains.

So basically, user will login through cp.domain.com , instead of domain.com:9001

I would greatly appreciate some insight into how this happens, i.e on other servers / setups. Arvixe uses cp.domain for all control panel access. I am also looking at various other scenario's where I want to use a global subdomain/pointer for different things, hence I would like to "understand" what needs to happen to DNS , IIS, and website panel, to achieve this.

Comment: Having the same issue, would love to know.

Comment: In a nutshell, if I remember correctly, you need an extra IP for unique things such as this. YOu need to "bind" the subdomain to that ip, and it should resolve for all domains on the other ip's. I might be off the track a little, this was a while ago for me. I did not want to offer up one of my ip's for cp, so I just stuck with the port. Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Thanks, what I ended up with was using a catch-all subdomain at the server level which then uses a script to redirect to the appropriate application.

Comment: Ahh yes, I remember such a script option in my research. Glad you got yours sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, if I remember correctly, you need an extra IP for unique things such as this. YOu need to "bind" the subdomain to that ip, and it should resolve for all domains on the other ip's. I might be off the track a little, this was a while ago for me. I did not want to offer up one of my ip's for cp, so I just stuck with the port.